# New installation-beginner - desktop but no Terminal /Shell / USB drives present or available

Tags: command-line

Have just installed 13.10  [ 64 bit ] on spare Windows XP ( 64 bit ) machine ie C drive is partitioned.

Desktop works fine but how do I access the Shell / Terminal  ?

Also none my USB drives are present - but my old floppy drive was.

[ I am trying to use Arduino software and to be able to plug in hardware to USB port - ie get Arduino sketches to work and use 'sudo' commands etc. ]

Sorry ,if this a stupid question but I am a complete novice.

SOLVED - GOT TERMINAL ICON  BY CTRL-ALT - T. FOUnD ARDUINO IDE DOWNLOAD IN ARBUNTU SOFTWARE CENTRE [ AFTER FAILING WITH THE sudo apt-get route ]  - SO FAR SO GOOD

Comment: Please edit your question to where there is only one question per post. Thanks

Comment: Please do not post your answer as part of the question. You can post your own answer at **Your Answer** below.

Answer (score 0):

I see you've found your answer already. Nevertheless, I'll repost here as an answer.

Just press `CTRL-ALT-T` on your keyboard. You could also launch a terminal **from the Dash** (press Super -Windows key- and type 'terminal') **or any other launcher** you may have installed.

If you want a 'real shell', press `CTRL-ALT-F1` to `CTRL-ALT-F6` for each shell you want to open.